# Javascript keydown event twice to cancel

Tags: javascript, keydown

My intention is to make div when keydown, and remove div when the same key is pressed again.
This is my code.

```js
let keydown = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    if (!keydown) {
      keydown = true;
      console.log("space")
      e.preventDefault(); //space doesn't manipulate position
      $("body").append($("<div id='refactor'></div>"))
      $(refactor).append($(".highlight").text())
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What should I do to remove the div when Space is hit again?

Comment: Your code snippet is throwing an error when I hit space, can you fix it, please?

Comment: as @JakubKotrs suggested, please fix your snippet as it throws an error as soon as we press the `spacebar`. Also, can you elaborate more on the condition to add/remove the `div` element.

Comment: you've implemented an action to act on `keydown === false` and toggled `keydown`, so surely you'd just add a second action for when `keydown===true`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all...jquery...avoid this bloatware by all means, please...

Of course this is based on what you've asked here, but I'd recommend instead of store `true`/`false` for the pressed key, store the new `div` element instead. This way, you'll have instant access to it without need search in the DOM.

To remove a node from the DOM, you just need execute `node.removeChild(child)`

```js
let div = null;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    console.log("space")
    e.preventDefault(); //space doesn't manipulate position

    if (div)
    {
      //remove div from DOM
      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      div = null;
    }
    else
    {
      //create new div
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "refactor";
      div.textContent = document.querySelector(".highlight").textContent;
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#refactor
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">test</div>
```

If your whole goal is to show/hide an element, than you should do so via CSS instead of adding/removing elements from DOM, it's significantly faster and allows add additional animations/styles:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("refactor");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    console.log("space")
    e.preventDefault(); //space doesn't manipulate position

    if (div.classList.contains("hidden"))
    {
      div.textContent = document.querySelector(".highlight").textContent + " " + Date();
    }

    div.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
})
```

```css
#refactor
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#refactor.hidden
{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">test</div>
<div id="refactor" class="hidden"></div>
<div>blah</div>
```